# How to read query strings without knowing variable's names?

Tags: php, query-string

I want to read all query strings that send from an URL, But I don't know variable's names to using `$_REQUEST['variable1']`.  So What I must do?

Comment: What are you going to do with the key pair values?

Comment: `print_r($_REQUEST)` or `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $var_name => $value) {
    //your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains all query strings that you want.

Answer (score 1):

you could do this
var_dump($_REQUEST);
It will dump everything onto screen for you